# QTableView lost selections after sorting

Tags: qt

I use `QSqlQueryModel` as the source model,  and added a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to provide custom sorting capacity. I found that after the user do the sorting, `tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows()` always returns an empty list even if in the GUI these rows are still clearly be "selected".

anyone knows the reason, my qt version is 4.8.3, thanks very much